# Rounding grand totals in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, grand-total, rounding

Is it possible to round the grand totals of checkout-cart up/down? 
I need a "[swedish rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cash_rounding)"?

Problem is I have some customized products with cent-prices, so I cannot change these fixed prices.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a module for swiss rounding (to 1/20th or 0.05) - it may help you:

https://packagist.org/packages/comsolit/rappenrunden

> This simple magento 2 module listens to the magento2 internal round()
>   function and rounds the price before to 1/20th (0.05). For example, a
>   value of 1,23 will be rounded up to 1,25 and a value of 0,97 will be
>   rounded down to 0,95.
>
> This functionality is particularly wide-spread in Switzerland, but is
>   not dependent on a specific currency.